# JPA Criteria Builder with two database functions together

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a table `MYTABLE` which has 3 columns as mentioned below.

```
|id | myclob_column | column3|
```

It has one column (`myclob_column`) which is **clob data (json)**. Sample clob data is below.

```
{
"name" : "Rahul",
"entry_date" : "2021-08-26T10:00:00Z"
}
```

`entry_date` field is in string. The below query works fine in oracle db when I convert the string to date by using `TO_DATE` function along with `JSON_VALUE` function.

```
select * from MYTABLE where TO_DATE( (JSON_VALUE(myclob_column, '$.entry_date')) , 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"' )  >= TO_DATE('2021-06-25T10:00:00Z' , 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"');
```

Now I am writing a code with Java JPA CriteriaBuilder.

```
Expression<Instant> dbFunction = criteriaBuilder.function("JSON_VALUE", String.class, '$.entry_date', 'myclob_column');
```

(`Instant.class` is Java class which represents date in 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"' format)

I have to apply another function `TO_DATE` as well along with `JSON_VALUE` because `JSON_VALUE` will return string date and I have to convert the string date to sql date datatype. How to use both the functions with CriteriaBuilder? Can you please guide.

**Note:** From java side, I will get date as `Instant class (not String)` from the web application user interface.

Comment: cb.function("to_date", Instant.class, cb.function("json_value", Object.class, root.get("myclob_column"),"$.entry_date"))

Comment: Thanks, it worked. If you post this in Answer section , I can accept the answer.